# Given a column with S3 paths, I want to read them and store the concatenated version of it. Pyspark

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a column with s3 file paths, I want to read all those paths, concatenate it later in PySpark[image]

Comment: how do you want to store the dataframes after reading the paths?

Comment: @samkart If possible, I would like to concatenate them and store it in a single parquet.

Comment: do they have same schema?

Comment: Exactly the same schema.

Comment: If the paths are the the same until a specific point, you can use wildcards, for example:

`spark.read.parquet("s3://etl-datahouse/my_stored_parquets/*")` under the assumption that all your files are stored under `my_stored_parquets` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the paths as a list using `map` and `collect`. Iterate over that list to read the paths and append the resulting spark dataframes into another list. Use the second list (which is a list of spark dataframes) to union all the dataframes.

```
# get all paths in a list
list_of_paths = data_sdf.rdd.map(lambda r: r.links).collect()

# read all paths and store the df in a list as element
list_of_sdf = []

for path in list_of_paths:
    list_of_sdf.append(spark.read.parquet(path))
# check using list_of_sdf[0].show() or list_of_sdf[1].printSchema()

# run union on all of the stored dataframes
import pyspark

final_sdf = reduce(pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.unionByName, list_of_sdf)
```

Use the `final_sdf` dataframe to write to a new parquet file.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply multiple paths to the Spark parquet read function. So, assuming these are paths to parquet files that you want to read into one DataFrame, you can do something like:

```
list_of_paths = [r.links for links_df.select("links").collect()]
aggregate_df = spark.read.parquet(*list_of_paths)
```